# Composer Repo on Bitbucket - Multiple packages

Tags: git, composer-php, bitbucket

I am able to have composer repo on bitbucket with this in client composer.json

```
"repositories": [
    { 
      "type": "vcs", 
      "url": "https://user@bitbucket.org/team/project.git"
    } 
]
```

That is working perfectly when i have 1 package on remote repo (project.git), but how i can have multiple packages, for example test_a and test_b, so they are available to repo clients?

I have tried on bitbucket to create test_a/composer.json and test_b/composer.json
but i guess i need some info in root that will be used to list all packages in that bitbucket repo.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can't put more than one package into one repository, you should simply use more repositories.

Adding these is as simple as adding more entries to "repositories":

```
"repositories": [
    { 
      "type": "vcs", 
      "url": "https://user@bitbucket.org/team/packageA.git"
    },
    { 
      "type": "vcs", 
      "url": "https://user@bitbucket.org/team/packageB.git"
    }
]
```

Ok, theoretically you could try to put different packages into different branches, and it might work. However, endless confusion would be the result, because you should also tag versions of a package - and there can only be one tag of the same version in this repository. Also, there can be only one branch named "master", so you'd have to change your branching strategy as well. This is not a good idea at all.

Comment: Repository by definition should have large amount of data not single peace of data. adding new repo in composer.json by end user for each package make no sense to me.

If it must be done on this way, than i will make repo mirror using Satis, so i have something like this:

client -> satis repo -> bitbucket (repoA, repoB)

In that case end user will have just to use satis mirror repo, but from other perspective that will require more things to do from my side - to edit Satis config every time when i add new package in new bitbucket and rebuild stuff, but i can have hook for that in bitbucket.

Comment: A Git repository by definition hosts ONE software artifact with one `composer.json` in the root folder. That's how Composer decided to do it. Use Satis - using these manual repositories will be annoying anyway, because you have to add ALL of them to the main project, even if they contain dependencies that a sub-sub-package needs (the repository definition in sub-packages are ignored due to possible infinite recursion).